# concatenate two different color spaces as input image for image.summary tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, python-imaging-library

I'm using tensorflow v1 and have a code which runs perfectly for one color space only (such as RGB or HSV)

```
Class Database_loader:

    #Defines a loading scheme for database
    
    def __init__(self, directory, size, proportion = 1.0, seed=42) :
        # data init
        self.dir = directory          # directory with the train / test / validation 
        self.size = size              # size of the sub image that should be croped
        self.nb_channels = 3          # return only the green channel of the images
        self.file_train = []          # list of the train images : tuple (image name / class)
        self.file_test = []           # list of the test images : tuple (image name / class)
        self.file_validation = []     # list of the validation images : tuple (image name / class)
        self.image_class = ['Real', 'CGG']         # list of the class (label) used in the process
        self.nb_class = 0
        self.train_iterator = 0       # iterator over the train images
        self.test_iterator = 0        # iterator over the test images
        self.validation_iterator = 0  # iterator over the validation images
        self.load_images(seed)        # load the data base

    def get_next_train(self) :

        # load next image (size should be big enough)
        image = []
        while True:
    
            # pop file name and class
            data = self.file_train[self.train_iterator]
            self.train_iterator += 1
            if self.train_iterator >= len(self.file_train) :
                self.train_iterator = 0

            # load image
            file_name = self.dir + '/train/' + data[1] + '/' + data[0]
            image = Image.open(file_name)                     
      
        # convert to float image
        image = image.astype(np.float32) / 255.      
        #image = image.reshape(1, self.size, self.size, 3)
    
        if self.size == None: 
            image = image.reshape(image.shape[0], image.shape[1], self.nb_channels)
        else: 
            image = image.reshape(self.size, self.size, self.nb_channels)
```

and the code for model:

```
def image_summaries(var, name):
    tf.summary.image(name + '_1', var[:,:,:,0:1], max_outputs = 1)
    tf.summary.image(name + '_2', var[:,:,:,1:2], max_outputs = 1)
    tf.summary.image(name + '_3', var[:,:,:,2:3], max_outputs = 1)

database_path = 'I:/users/Database/test/'


# to change to the format of your image
image_size = 100

# define a single-image classifier
clf = Model(database_path, image_size, config = 'Personal', filters = [32,32,64],
            batch_size = 50, feature_extractor = 'Stats', 
            remove_filter_size = 5, using_GPU = True)

# trains the classifier and test it on the testing set
clf.train(nb_train_batch = 800,
          nb_test_batch = 80, 
          nb_validation_batch = 40,
          validation_frequency = 20,
          show_filters = False)
```

but i want to concatenate rgb images and hsv images in channel dimension and have 6 number of channels instead of 3 channels so i made these changes:

```
        self.nb_channels = 6
```

```
        image1 = image.convert("HSV")
        t1 = np.asarray(image1)
        t2 = np.asarray(image) 
        t3 = np.concatenate((t1, t2))
        image2 = Image.fromarray(t3)
        image = np.asarray(image2)

        # convert to float image
        image = image.astype(np.float32) / 255.
```

```
        def image_summaries(var, name):
          tf.summary.image(name + '_1', var[:,:,:,0:1], max_outputs = 1)
          tf.summary.image(name + '_2', var[:,:,:,1:2], max_outputs = 1)
          tf.summary.image(name + '_3', var[:,:,:,2:3], max_outputs = 1)
          tf.summary.image(name + '_4', var[:,:,:,3:4], max_outputs = 1)
          tf.summary.image(name + '_5', var[:,:,:,4:5], max_outputs = 1)
          tf.summary.image(name + '_6', var[:,:,:,5:6], max_outputs = 1)
```

and got this error:

> InvalidArgumentError: Tensor must be 4-D with last dim 1, 3, or 4, not [50,100,100,6]
> [[Node: Input_Data/Image_Visualization/Input_Data = ImageSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, bad_color=Tensor<type: uint8 shape: [4] values: 255 0 0...>, max_images=3, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Input_Data/Image_Visualization/Input_Data/tag, Input_Data/Reshape/_91)]]

any idea about what i should do?

Comment: I don't think you can do this; at least not without some significant changes to the model.

Comment: i'm new to tensorflow and it seems it's `image.summary` that caused this problem. is there any way to use other command than  `image.summary` ?